# iterating a list and passing results through a function and saving results in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, function

I have this list :

Peer_List_Members = [1967, 2338, 421, 1275, 2499, 2240, 881, 2719, 2894, 2198, 3120, 3160, 635]

I iterate over this list as follows:

```
for x in Peer_List_Members:
        x = ID_Search(str(x))
        print(x)
```

The above function passes each element through the function "ID_Search(input_id)" that then looks up the numbers' values in a database and gives the lookup value back:

```
def ID_Search(input_id): 
    returns_name = pd.read_sql_query("""
    SELECT BaseHoldingID
    FROM Holdings
    WHERE HoldingID=""" + input_id
    , conn)
    returns_name = pd.DataFrame(returns_name)
    BaseHoldingID = returns_name['BaseHoldingID'][0]
    return(BaseHoldingID)
```

The output from the print(x) is as follows:

```
1774
2134
421
1267
2295
2046
867
2517
2694
2010
2874
2913
629
```

But when iterate and try to save to a new list (lst) using:

```
lst=[]
for x in Peer_List_Members:
    x = ID_Search(str(x))
    lst.append(x)
    print(lst)
```

I get this weird output!

```
[1774]
[1774, 2134]
[1774, 2134, 421]
[1774, 2134, 421, 1267]
[1774, 2134, 421, 1267, 2295]
[1774, 2134, 421, 1267, 2295, 2046]
[1774, 2134, 421, 1267, 2295, 2046, 867]
[1774, 2134, 421, 1267, 2295, 2046, 867, 2517]
...........
[1774, 2134, 421, 1267, 2295, 2046, 867, 2517, 2694, 2010, 2874, 2913, 629]
```

QUESTION: first how do I fix the weird output when appending.  BUT ideally I want to combine the original list with the new list into a dataframe.

Thanks for any and all help!  Much appreciated.

Comment: You only create an empty list once, so each time you go through your list you are adding the latest item and printing the whole list, instead of printing the latest entry. If you only want to print the most recent item, you could do `print(lst[-1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I did some digginh/googling and was able to find a way...

```
def peerBaseHolding():
     return [ID_Search(str(number)) for number in Peer_List_Members]

peerBaseHolding = peerBaseHolding()
peerBaseHolding = pd.DataFrame(peerBaseHolding, columns={'BaseHoldingID'})
Peer_List_Members = pd.DataFrame(Peer_List_Members, columns={'HoldingID'})

peerList = Peer_List_Members.merge(peerBaseHolding, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
peerList
```

It works but is there abetter way to do this?